# How to draw relative to the bottom of the browser window on an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have a large canvas which takes up more than 100% of the height of a browser's viewing window.  I want normal page scrolling to access the unseen parts of the canvas (this is already implemented).  Most of the graphics on the canvas are drawn with normal positioning (relative to the canvas's origin).  However occasionally, the part of the canvas that is off screen might contain a bit of information that is so vital, I'd like to indicate it on the canvas at the bottom of the screen (ie: drawn on the canvas but positioned relative to the browser).

Comment: This is frustrating.  The only answer I have is what I've come up with myself.  My answer has a down vote, but no one has told me why my answer was bad or how to improve it, even though it asks for feedback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a working answer:

```
var bounding = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var y_relative = window.innerHeight - bounding.top;
context.fillText("I will always be at the bottom of the screen!", x+margin, y_relative-fontSize-margin);
```

Will this always work?  What about people with browser plugins that take up screen real estate?  Any other issues I haven't even though of?